# MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.Connection

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, struts

I built an web application and deployed locally working perfect.  I deployed it on a remote server and started getting the :
exception

```
> javax.servlet.ServletException: could not execute query 
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:518) 
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:421) 


>root cause 

>org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query 
org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:74) 
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43) 
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2223) 
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104) 
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099) 
org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:94) 
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569) 
org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283) 
data.dao.UserDAO.findByUsername(UserDAO.java:42) 
action.registration.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:24) 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:399) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:262) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:213) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:150) 
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:48) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:123) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.intercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:161) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:105) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:83) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:207) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:74) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:127) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:107) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:206) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:115) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:143) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.intercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:115) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:170) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:123) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:50) 
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:507) 
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:421) 

>root cause 

>com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.Connection was implicitly closed due to underlying exception/error: 


** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 
    >com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException 
MESSAGE: Communications link failure 

>Last packet sent to the server was 43 ms ago. 

>STACKTRACE: 

>com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure 

>Last packet sent to the server was 43 ms ago. 
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2871) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3414) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1885) 
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186) 
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787) 
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674) 
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236) 
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1860) 
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:48) 
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:42) 
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3042) 
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:395) 
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:375) 
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:139) 
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:195) 
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:103) 
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:878) 
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:815) 
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:808) 
at data.base._BaseRootDAO.get(_BaseRootDAO.java:228) 
at data.base._BaseRootDAO.get(_BaseRootDAO.java:217) 
at data.base.BaseUserDAO.get(BaseUserDAO.java:49) 
at util.UserUtil.getUser(UserUtil.java:22) 
at action.market.ArmsDealerAction.display(ArmsDealerAction.java:62) 
at action.market.ArmsDealerAction.displayUser(ArmsDealerAction.java:54) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:399) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:262) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:213) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:150) 
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:48) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:123) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.intercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:161) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:105) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:83) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:207) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:74) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:127) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:107) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
at 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:123) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:174) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) 
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108) 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:151) 
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:874) 
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) 
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost. 
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2431) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2882) 
... 141 more 


** END NESTED EXCEPTION ** 


>sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor72.newInstance(Unknown Source) 
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) 
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) 
com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406) 
com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381) 
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984) 
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956) 
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926) 
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1098) 
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4076) 
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4042) 
org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:505) 
org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:423) 
org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:139) 
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1547) 
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:673) 
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236) 
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220) 
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104) 
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099) 
org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:94) 
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569) 
org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283) 
data.dao.UserDAO.findByUsername(UserDAO.java:42) 
action.registration.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:24) 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:399) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:262) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:213) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:150) 
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:48) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:123) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.intercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:161) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:105) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:83) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:207) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:74) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:127)
```

I have used hibernate and struts to build web application and deploy the web application in Linux server.Its login functionality working well for some time, But after that login not working and showing above Exception in Tomcat Log File.

Comment: is there something missing?
"com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.Connection was implicitly closed due to underlying exception/error:"
shouldn't there be a bit more?

Comment: pls see the below exception area.

Comment: sounds silly but is the database still working after that exception. can you connect to it with mysql workbench or via terminal and execute a query?

Comment: Actually is it occured at the time of login.When I am going to login in my web Application,It is working fine but after couple of hours logging process is not working.My web application doesn't accept the user and pass.I have checked my tomcat log file it is showing above Exception.One more thing,If we restart tomcat it is again working properly and accept the user and password.my web Application working on hibernate(MySql) and struts technology.

Comment: and how do you get your hibernate session into your dao?
since there is a time factor i assume, that your connection might be timed out and this instance of the timedout connection is used, so basically you need to create a new hibernate session. that's just an early assumption.

Comment: Session mysession = (Session) DAO.session.get();
        if (mysession == null || !mysession.isOpen()) {
            mysession = sessionFactory.openSession();
            DAO.session.set(mysession);
        }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12016/discussion-between-atu-tha-and-tagtraeumer)

Comment: Can you show the code for the method that actually uses a java.sql.Connection object? Or is that all buried in Hibernate?

Comment: DAO is my connection class and below getSession() is connection function.
 public static synchronized Session getSession() {

        Session mysession = (Session) DAO.session.get();
        if (mysession == null || !mysession.isOpen()) {
            mysession = sessionFactory.openSession();
            DAO.session.set(mysession);
        }

        return mysession;
    }

Comment: hi lieven are  u there?

Comment: Hi Atul, I know this subject is old but currently my app is experiencing exactly the same and perhaps you can remember the way to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the error stacktrace, your connection to MySQL server is lost.

```
>root cause 

>com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
  No operations allowed after connection closed.
  Connection was implicitly closed due to underlying exception/error: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 
    >com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException 
MESSAGE: Communications link failure 

>Last packet sent to the server was 43 ms ago. 

>STACKTRACE: 

>com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

It is very clear that the root cause is `Communications link failure`.

Try pinging your database server and see if you are able to connect.
Else resolve the network issue and then connect. No alternatives for this.

You can issue a light weight `ping` to your database server to check the connection availability.
Please read following discussion and articles:

1. [Ping MySQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569956/ping-a-mysql-server)
2. [Ping syntax and example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-connection-pooling.html)

Comment: Ravinder it's problem occured in linux server at the time of login in my web application.

Comment: @AtuTha - I don't think it does matter on which server it happened.

Comment: It can be anything like, network card failure, server time out, server down.

Answer (score 2):

Just check once whether you have added **@Repository** annotation in the Repository class.
because this could also be main reason for the exception.