# Connecting to a Remote Database through Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, raspberry-pi

I have a mysql database created on a raspberry pi, I want to access it through a java application running on a laptop in the same local network.

I tried connecting that same application with another database on another computer on the network and it worked. I don't know why it isn't working with the RPI.

i connect through the following command:

```
String URL = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.11.157/DB_name";
try {
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

However, an exception is thrown and ERROR: Unable to Connect to Database. is printed to the console.

Edit:

Knowing that:
 * I can access the database through a local app running on the same raspberry pi (i used @local).
 * Can Successfully ping & SSH with the raspberry pi, even run the program mentioned in the previous point through the SSH and it works fine.

The stack trace:

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has      not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:358)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2489)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2311)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:347)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.climacon.jdbc.db.JDBCMySQLConnection.createConnection(JDBCMySQLConnection.java:42)
at com.climacon.jdbc.db.JDBCMySQLConnection.getConnection(JDBCMySQLConnection.java:51)
at com.climacon.jdbc.main.ClimaConJDBC.get_Nodeinfo_From_DB(ClimaConJDBC.java:110)
at com.climacon.gui.ClimaCon2$5.actionPerformed(ClimaCon2.java:279)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: For a start you should print out the exception that you are getting, it may just let you know what the problem is.

Comment: Replace catch block with  } catch (SQLException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();         }
Then post the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

1. Go into the my.cnf file (sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf) file and
   look for `"bind-address"` and make it `“bind-address = * “`
2. Reload MySQL config (sudo service mysql reload)
3. Restart MySQL server (sudo service mysql restart)

Answer (score 4):

I think the reason you can not access the remote mysql may be due to the remote access restriction in `my.cnf`
please check the line
`bind-address:` is set to `127.0.0.1`
under this restriction, you can not connect remotely with that mysql server;
to solve this, you need to change this line to:
`bind-address: 0.0.0.0`

in addition you should specify the port for connection as below:
`String URL = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.11.157:3306/DB_name";`
because mysql will connect port 3306 in default.
wish my answer could help you!

Comment: sorry , but i don't really know where i can find mysql.cnf or how to open it, i am new to mysql , databases &  servers in general.

Comment: if you are using linux, you can find it in /etc/mysql/my.cnf. sorry for the typo in my answer!

Comment: I found the following tutorial:

1. Grant access to your remote machine.
2. Go into the my.cnf file (sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf) file and look for "bind-address" and comment this out (put a # in front of the line) 
3. Reload MySQL config (service mysql reload) 
4. Restart MySQL server (service mysql restart) 

Since i have already done number 1 , i did number 2 (also tried to make it 0.0.0.0 as you said).
However, when i use service mysql reload , i get the following message: Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted

Comment: You directed me in the right way , it was the bind-address as you thought, however, must use reload after modifying.

Thank you

Comment: actually I just like to restart after modified my.cnf

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the next things:

1. Is the database active? Does it respond to another application except yours?
2. Is the network connection OK (eg firewall)?
3. Check the [connection strings](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-db-connections.htm) (perhaps the port is necessairy but I am not sure).

I am not really familiar with the raspberry. It seems that it's using a linux operating system (correct me if I am wrong). In [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5334/how-can-i-disable-raspbmcs-firewall-via-ssh) post, instruction are given on how to disable firewall on the device. It says that the firewall is the usual [iptables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) firewall used on linux systems. I find [this iptables tutorial (based on ubuntu)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) very useful. Perhaps it would give you some guidance.

Hope I helped!

Comment: 1- Until now, the database only responds to another java application that runs on the same raspberry pi (i am using @localhost in that application), but i am trying to build the first app to access it from another computer and that's what isn't working.

2- No idea about any firewall settings on the raspberry pi.

3- I think i got it right, because i was able to access the same database, when it was on my computer. I just used the ip as mentioned above.

Comment: Check my edited answer. I put the details on the main answer body to be more easily accessible for other users.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, but i want to ask a question before going into these details.

If there is a problem with the firewall , will i be able to SSH into the Raspberry pi & Also could ping from the terminal ?
Because both work fine with me right now.

Comment: I cannot really give you an answer on accessing the Raspberry pi through SSH. I cannot see a reason why you wouldn't be able to access it through SSH, but as I said I am not an expert on this device. I suppose [this](http://cplus.about.com/od/raspberrypi/a/How-Do-I-Setup-Ssh-On-Raspberry-Pi.htm) could provide some guidance...

Comment: You misunderstood me,
What i am saying is that I CAN SUCCESSFULLY Access the raspberry pi through SSH, so, can the problem i am facing still be a firewall problem?

IF it was a firewall problem, isn't it supposed that SSH will not work too ?

Comment: Sorry. I indeed misunderstood. Yes, it could still be a firewall problem, despite the working SSH. [SSH uses well known port 22](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers). This means that in some systems, these ports are by default open. On the other hand, the firewall could have the port used by JDBC (3306) closed.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to ping the `raspberry pi` but I am not sure what the interface used is.

Why don't you use `MySQL Ping` and see if it is responding?
Else it must be a network issue. Get it resolved and then connect. No alternatives for this.

You can issue a light weight `ping` to your database server to check the connection availability.
Please read following discussion and articles:

1. [Ping MySQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569956/ping-a-mysql-server)
2. [Ping syntax and example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-connection-pooling.html)
3. [My answer to one of such *Communication link failures*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10847193/767881).

Answer (score -1):

The url  "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb".

You lost the port 3306.

Comment: `port` is optional. And even `localhost` if on local machine.

Comment: Also OP is using `String URL = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.11.157/DB_name";`

Comment: Can you access to the server 192.168.11.157?

Answer (score -3):

you need to print the exception to the console ,rather than print a customer "error",If you do 
 as that ,you can't get the key of the problem

Comment: this should be in comment, not answer.