# tomcat-jdbc pool datasource not reconnecting

Tags: jdbc, spring-boot, connection-pooling, jdbctemplate, tomcat-jdbc

I have a spring boot application with the following data source setup:

application.properties:

```
tomcat.jdbc.pool.url=jdbc:mysql://url/db
tomcat.jdbc.pool.username=username
tomcat.jdbc.pool.password=password
tomcat.jdbc.pool.initial-size=10
tomcat.jdbc.pool.test-on-borrow=true
tomcat.jdbc.pool.test-while-idle=true
tomcat.jdbc.pool.validation-query=SELECT 1
tomcat.jdbc.pool.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
tomcat.jdbc.pool.max_size=30
tomcat.jdbc.pool.min_size=7
```

DataSourceConfiguration.java

```
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;


@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Value("${tomcat.jdbc.pool.max_size}")
    private int maxSize;

    @Value("${tomcat.jdbc.pool.min_size}")
    private int minSize;

    @Value("${tomcat.jdbc.pool.initial-size}")
    private int initialSize;

    @Value("${tomcat.jdbc.pool.test-on-borrow}")
    private boolean testOnBorrow;

    @Value("${tomcat.jdbc.pool.test-while-idle}")
    private boolean testWhileIdle;

    @Value("${tomcat.jdbc.pool.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${tomcat.jdbc.pool.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${tomcat.jdbc.pool.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${tomcat.jdbc.pool.driver-class-name}")
    private String driverClassName;

    @Value("${tomcat.jdbc.pool.validation-query}")
    private String validationQuery;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSource.setValidationQuery(validationQuery);
        dataSource.setInitialSize(initialSize);
        dataSource.setMaxIdle(maxSize);
        dataSource.setMinIdle(minSize);
        dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(testOnBorrow);
        dataSource.setTestWhileIdle(testWhileIdle);
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

And finally I have a repository that utilizes this datasource in a jdbcTemplate:

```
@Repository
public class PositionRepository {

    private static JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public PositionRepository() {}

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

I confirmed that the datasource being passed to the JdbcTemplate constructor is indeed org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource.

Every now and then, however, I get the following exception:

```
[2015-09-29 10:44:40.098] boot - 14124  INFO [http-nio-8888-exec-5] --- XmlBeanDefinitionReader: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
[2015-09-29 10:44:40.302] boot - 14124  INFO [http-nio-8888-exec-5] --- SQLErrorCodesFactory: SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, Hana]
[2015-09-29 10:44:40.308] boot - 14124  WARN [http-nio-8888-exec-5] --- SQLErrorCodesFactory: Error while extracting database product name - falling back to empty error codes
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:305) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:329) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory.getErrorCodes(SQLErrorCodesFactory.java:214) [spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.setDataSource(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:134) [spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.<init>(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:97) [spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.getExceptionTranslator(JdbcAccessor.java:99) [spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:416) [spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:471) [spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:481) [spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForList(JdbcTemplate.java:521) [spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.myproj.somename.repositories.PositionRepository.runQueryForList(PositionRepository.java:34) [classes/:?]
    at org.myproj.somename.repositories.PositionRepository.positionFindPaged(PositionRepository.java:52) [classes/:?]
    at org.myproj.somename.repositories.PositionRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ce8ed984.invoke(<generated>) [spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717) [spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) [spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653) [spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.myproj.somename.repositories.PositionRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a986c62b.positionFindPaged(<generated>) [spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.myproj.somename.controllers.api.Positions.runPositions(Positions.java:148) [classes/:?]
    at org.myproj.somename.controllers.api.Positions.runPositions(Positions.java:93) [classes/:?]
    at org.myproj.somename.controllers.api.Positions.getPositions(Positions.java:61) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-

embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
        at ....
.....
.....
.....
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [?:1.8.0]
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408) ~[?:1.8.0]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:372) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:958) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:937) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:872) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1236) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1231) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getMetaData(ConnectionImpl.java:2938) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getMetaData(ConnectionImpl.java:2933) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[?:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.23.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.23.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.23.jar:?]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.getMetaData(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:294) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        ... 103 more
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

    The last packet successfully received from the server was 16,234 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1 milliseconds ago.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408) ~[?:1.8.0]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1038) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3422) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3322) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3762) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2531) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2489) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1446) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:455) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:405) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        ... 97 more
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2914) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3332) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3322) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3762) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2531) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2489) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1446) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:455) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:405) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        ... 97 more
    [2015-09-29 10:44:40.344] boot - 14124 ERROR [http-nio-8888-exec-5] --- [dispatcherServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.RecoverableDataAccessException: StatementCallback; SQL [SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ticker, `type`, strike, expiration, SUM(premium) / COUNT(*) avg_premium, SUM(newquantity)*multiplier `position` FROM ( SELECT IF (ACTION = 'BOUGHT', quantity, -quantity) newquantity, e.ticker_eurex ticker, e.multiplier, tr.*  FROM trade_record tr JOIN equity e ON tr.equity_id = e.id)  a WHERE  (  `expiration` >= '2015-09-29'  ) and  true  and trade_date <= '2015-07-09'  GROUP BY ticker, TYPE, strike, expiration ORDER BY  expiration desc , strike asc , position desc  LIMIT 0,100 ) z  WHERE  true  AND position <> 0 ]; Communications link failure

    The last packet successfully received from the server was 16,234 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1 milliseconds ago.; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

    The last packet successfully received from the server was 16,234 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1 milliseconds ago.] with root cause
    java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2914) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3332) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3322) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3762) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2531) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2489) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1446) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:455) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:405) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:471) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:481) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForList(JdbcTemplate.java:521) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.myproj.somename.repositories.PositionRepository.runQueryForList(PositionRepository.java:34) ~[classes/:?]
        at org.myproj.somename.repositories.PositionRepository.positionFindPaged(PositionRepository.java:52) ~[classes/:?]
        at org.myproj.somename.repositories.PositionRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ce8ed984.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.myproj.somename.repositories.PositionRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a986c62b.positionFindPaged(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.myproj.somename.controllers.api.Positions.runPositions(Positions.java:148) ~[classes/:?]
        at org.myproj.somename.controllers.api.Positions.runPositions(Positions.java:93) ~[classes/:?]
        at org.myproj.somename.controllers.api.Positions.getPositions(Positions.java:61) ~[classes/:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[?:1.8.0]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    .....
    .....
    ....


    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0]
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0]
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [?:1.8.0]
```

Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong. Isn't the whole point of using connection pooling to avoid this type of issues? Can I somehow tell tomcat-jdbc that I don't want exceptions unless it tried to reconnect X number of times? On top of that setTestOnBorrow and setTestOnIdle are both set to true.

Anyone has any ideas what's going on? Am I doing something wrong in my setup?

Cheers and thanks in advance!

P.S.

I truncated the exception at one point in order to fit within the max char limit of SO.

Comment: root couse is [Communications link failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845703/mysqlnontransientconnectionexception-no-operations-allowed-after-connection-clo)

Comment: I know but this exception happens rarely and when it happens I just need to resubmit the ajax call and it works so the db is not down for a prolonged period of time or anything like that. I do realize the mysql server is probably at fault here for the exception but isn't tomcat-jdbc supposed to handle these cases?

Comment: Without knowing the implementation details - simple consideration: If the session is broken after the last execution and returned to the pool, it can be validated on the next borrow and rejected. But if you fail in the middle of you execution steps you'll need to catch and handle the exception on your own.

Comment: Gotcha - thanks for the info. I just added my own reconnect logic and it seems to work fine. It really does appear it's a db problem because it takes it a couple of seconds (i.e. 2 retries @ the current rate) before the reconnect logic manages to complete the query.

Comment: After wasting a few days of my life I finally moved to HakariCP and I could not be happier. I'm getting the same SQL connection exceptions but HakariCP handles them like a champ and my retry logic is not even kicking in. Thanks for nothing tomcat-jdbc. Will definitely not use that crap again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long story short, I eventually ended up ditching jdbc-pool because it turned out to be an absolute waste of time. I decided to give HikariCP a shot with my Spring Boot backend and I couldn't be happier. It started handling the disconnection issues automatically and gracefully after a super basic setup.

If you're running Spring Boot all you need is to add this to your pom.xml

```
<!-- HikariCP DB Connection Pooling -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and then you just need to set the HikariCP properties accordingly. This is my setup and I had 0 problems with it

```
# hikariCP
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/some_db_name?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&dumpQueriesOnException=true
spring.datasource.username=<your_username_here>
spring.datasource.password=<your_password_here>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.pool-name=SpringBootHikariCP
spring.datasource.maximum-pool-size=8
spring.datasource.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.max-lifetime=2000000
spring.datasource.connection-timeout=30000
spring.datasource.idle-timeout=30000
spring.datasource.pool-prepared-statements=true
spring.datasource.max-open-prepared-statements=250
spring.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.pool-prepared-statements=true
spring.datasource.pool-prepared-statements-cache-size=250
spring.datasource.pool-prepared-statements-cache-sql-limit=2048
spring.datasource.user-server-prepared-statements=true
```

And finally this was the corresponding DataSource configuration using the properties above

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    // HikariCP

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String driverClassName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.pool-name}")
    private String poolName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.connection-timeout}")
    private int connectionTimeout;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.max-lifetime}")
    private int maxLifetime;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.maximum-pool-size}")
    private int maximumPoolSize;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.minimum-idle}")
    private int minimumIdle;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.idle-timeout}")
    private int idleTimeout;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.validation-query}")
    private String validationQuery;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.pool-prepared-statements}")
    private String cachePrepStmts;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.pool-prepared-statements-cache-size}")
    private String prepStmtCacheSize;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.pool-prepared-statements-cache-sql-limit}")
    private String prepStmtCacheSqlLimit;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.user-server-prepared-statements}")
    private String useServerPrepStmts;

    @Bean
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {

        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(url); 
        hikariConfig.setUsername(username);
        hikariConfig.setPassword(password);
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(maximumPoolSize);
        hikariConfig.setMinimumIdle(minimumIdle);
        hikariConfig.setConnectionTimeout(connectionTimeout);
        hikariConfig.setIdleTimeout(idleTimeout);
        hikariConfig.setConnectionTestQuery(validationQuery);
        hikariConfig.setPoolName("springHikariCP");

        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.cachePrepStmts", cachePrepStmts);
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize", prepStmtCacheSize);
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", prepStmtCacheSqlLimit);
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.useServerPrepStmts", useServerPrepStmts);

        HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
        return ds;
    }

}
```

That's what resolved the problem for me.