# How to ping MySQL database using spring datasource properties

Tags: java, mysql, spring, heroku

I'm using Spring Boot with the following `application.properties` file for my database setup:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://<my heroku cleardb host...>/<my db>
spring.datasource.username=<some user...>
spring.datasource.password=<some pass...>
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I'm hosting my site on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com) with [ClearDB MySQL Database](https://addons.heroku.com/cleardb).  My app keeps getting disconnected from the MySQL DB and it's because of this (from their support team):

> To jump in here about this issue - the reason is that our systems
>   automatically close all idle connections after 90 seconds of
>   inactivity. This could be the reason you are running into this issue, 
>   especially if your connection pool is not properly configured to
>   "ping" connections in less than  around 90 seconds. Our recommendation
>   would be to set the connection pool configuration to ping all  pooled
>   connections once every 60 seconds for safe keeping.

So the question is...how can I "ping" my connections every 60 seconds?  I would like to believe that there is a way to set a `spring.datasource` property to do this but I'm having trouble finding a 'ping' property.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ping a MySQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569956/ping-a-mysql-server)

Comment: I could ping MySQL programmatically but I would like to know if there's a `spring.datasource` property I can set for "pinging" the server

Comment: If you are using i.e. `Apache DBCP`, you could use `testOnBorrow` to validate your connections. Also, you would have to set `validationQuery` to `SELECT 1`.

Comment: Check the Spring Boot docs [for properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties). Look at the test properties and validation query. At least you want the test on borrow that way if the connection is borked it will reconnect